# GNU Make strange variable substitutions

Tags: linux, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
CPPCOMPILER=g++
CCOMPILER=gcc
#CPPCOMPILER=i586-mingw32msvc-g++

FLAGS=-Wall -g -O3
LIBRARIES=-lpthread
MODULES=obj/HTTPRequest.o obj/main.o obj/Server.o obj/SocketUtils.o obj/HTTPServer.o \
    obj/CookieManager.o obj/FileLister.o
STATIC=obj/static/files.html.o obj/static/login.html.o

all: $(MODULES) $(STATIC)
    $(CPPCOMPILER) $(MODULES) $(STATIC) $(LIBRARIES) -o httpserver

obj/main.o : main.cpp
    @mkdir -p obj
    $(CPPCOMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@ 

obj/static/%.o : %
    @mkdir -p obj/static
    file2obj $< $(subst .,_,$<) > $<.c
    $(CCOMPILER) $<.c -o $@ -c $(FLAGS)   #<-------***THIS LINE***

obj/%.o : %.cpp %.h
    @mkdir -p obj
    $(CPPCOMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    rm -rf $(STATIC) $(MODULES) httpserver
```

I have `files.html` for which `file2obj` emits C source code. This code gets compiled to .o file.

However the `make` process is somewhat different that what I expected. Here's the output:

```
thrustmaster@thrustmaster:~/Code/HTTPFileSharer$ make
cc     files.html.c   -o files.html #<--------- ****THIS LINE!****
[and more linker errors here because of wrong command]
make: *** [files.html] Error 1
```

- How can `cc` get invoked in this case? I expect `gcc`. (I faced similar issues in another project too, but the results weren't serious.)
- And how come it eats up some of the parameters? Also `-o` parameter is wrong.(I get `-o files.html`)
- A few times `files.html` got deleted. Any ideas as to what can be the reason behind it?

I am using GNU make 3.81.

Is there anything wrong with my Makefile code? Or is it some known bug in GNU/make?

Any advice/pointers/suggestiosn will be greatly appreciated :-)

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

I am putting here another case, where I am facing a similar problem.

Makefile:

```
CPPCOMPILER=g++
CCOMPILER=gcc
FLAGS=-Wall -pg -O3
LIBRARIES=`pkg-config --libs libglfw` -lm -lGLU -lGL -lXrandr
UNITS=obj/main.o obj/TextureManager.o obj/Thread.o obj/Tile.o obj/PictureTile.o     obj/Coverflow.o obj/Vector3D.o \
        obj/TilePopulator.o obj/FileLister.o
SOIL_DEPENDS=soil/image_DXT.c  soil/image_helper.c  soil/SOIL.c  soil/stbi_DDS_aug_c.h      soil/stb_image_aug.c \
                soil/image_DXT.h  soil/image_helper.h  soil/SOIL.h  soil/stbi_DDS_aug.h      soil/stb_image_aug.h
SOIL_UNITS=obj/soil/image_DXT.o obj/soil/image_helper.o obj/soil/SOIL.o     soil/stb_image_aug.o

all: $(SOIL_UNITS) $(UNITS)
        $(CPPCOMPILER) $(FLAGS) $(SOIL_UNITS) $(UNITS) $(LIBRARIES) -o coverflow

obj/soil/%.o : soil/%.c
        @mkdir -p obj/soil
        $(CCOMPILER) -c $< -o $@     #<--Issue in this line 

obj/main.o : main.cpp
        @mkdir -p obj
        $(CPPCOMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@ 
obj/%.o : %.cpp %.h
        @mkdir -p obj
        $(CPPCOMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@ 
clean:
        rm -rf $(UNITS) $(SOIL_UNITS) coverflow
```

OUTPUT:

```
thrustmaster@thrustmaster:~/Code/Skroll$ make
gcc -c soil/image_DXT.c -o obj/soil/image_DXT.o
gcc -c soil/image_helper.c -o obj/soil/image_helper.o
gcc -c soil/SOIL.c -o obj/soil/SOIL.o
cc    -c -o soil/stb_image_aug.o soil/stb_image_aug.c  #<-----**THIS LINE**
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 main.cpp -o obj/main.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 TextureManager.cpp -o obj/TextureManager.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 Thread.cpp -o obj/Thread.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 Tile.cpp -o obj/Tile.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 PictureTile.cpp -o obj/PictureTile.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 Coverflow.cpp -o obj/Coverflow.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 Vector3D.cpp -o obj/Vector3D.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 TilePopulator.cpp -o obj/TilePopulator.o 
g++ -c -Wall -pg -O3 FileLister.cpp -o obj/FileLister.o 
g++ -Wall -pg -O3 obj/soil/image_DXT.o obj/soil/image_helper.o obj/soil/SOIL.o     soil/stb_image_aug.o obj/main.o obj/TextureManager.o obj/Thread.o obj/Tile.o     obj/PictureTile.o obj/Coverflow.o obj/Vector3D.o obj/TilePopulator.o obj/FileLister.o `pkg-    config --libs libglfw` -lm -lGLU -lGL -lXrandr -o coverflow
```

Comment: If `files.html.c` is newer than `files.html`, why do you *not* want to rebuild `files.html`?

Comment: @Beta I didn't get what you are trying to suggest. `files.html.c` is _generated_ using the `file2obj` application (and is later compiled to object file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you are trying to build `obj/static/files.html.o` using this rule:

```
obj/static/%.o : %
    @mkdir -p obj/static
    file2obj $< $(subst .,_,$<) > $<.c
    $(CCOMPILER) $<.c -o $@ -c $(FLAGS)
```

Before Make runs this rule, it will first check to see if the prerequisite (`files.html`) can/should be rebuilt. There is an implicit rule that will build `files.html` from `files.html.c`, so that's what will happen *if `files.html.c` exists*. (You seem to be going in the opposite direction from what Make expects; I don't know enough about building HTML to know if that's a good idea.) And if that works, Make will consider `files.html` an [intermediate file](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules), and will delete it when it is no longer needed.

There's more than one way to solve this problem. The simplest is probably to write your own rule for building `files.html`, which overrules Make's rule and does nothing:

```
%.html: %.html.c;
```

In the second case you made a small mistake in your `SOIL_UNITS` variable:

```
SOIL_UNITS=obj/soil/image_DXT.o obj/soil/image_helper.o obj/soil/SOIL.o soil/stb_image_aug.o
```

Notice the last term. You have a rule for `obj/soil/%.o`, but not for `soil/%.o`, so Make falls back on its implicit rule. Just change that term to `obj/soil/stb_image_aug.o`.

Comment: This one helps! :)
And its a bit embarrassing to see that stupid error in the second case (and it didn't make much of a difference back then -- gcc or cc both were fine) :P

In the first case, what I am trying to do is, 'embed' files into the application program. I wrote another utility for the same (`file2obj`), and the build path is: `files.html` -> `files.html.c` -> `files.html.o` -> linked executable. I used the rule: `obj/static/%.html.o : %.html` but I have to add a new rule for every extension. Any other way out (one which does not lose out on generality?)

Thanks a ton +1 :-)

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Eh? You want to use *the same rule* for several different extensions?

Comment: Yes! By having *.html, I must write as many rules as there are extensions. Is there any way I can write rules that will take care of all possible files inside a certain directory (as in this eg, 'static' folder)? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

GNU Make has a built-in implicit rule for building a file, X, from X.c:

```
%: %.c
#  commands to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

It appears this implicit rule is being invoked when you run "make".

While not a good permanent solution, you may be able to avoid this problem by running make with the `-r` (or `--no-builtin-rules`) option to disable the implicit rules.

Comment: I have updated the question with another similar case. If what you are saying is correct, shouldn't it be affecting all the C files? It is rather affecting only the last one. Any idea as to why it is happening?

Comment: The problem is this rule: `obj/static/%.o : %`

Perhaps it should be changed to: `obj/static/%.o : %.c`

Then split the file2obj recipe to a separate rule:

`%.html.c : %.html
    file2obj $< $(subst .,_,$<) > $<.c`